# Get all posts from categories

Tags: php

I am trying to print all posts from all categories but the posts to show within category at this moment its printing all the posts below all categories. Here is the code. Yo can use the shortcode [bpo_microsoft_shortcode]. Thanks in advance:

```
        <?php
        function Custom_Post_Type_Grouped_By_Category(){ 
            global $post;
            $cat_args = array(
                'orderby'       => 'term_id', 
                'order'         => 'ASC',
                'hide_empty'    => true, 
            );    
            $terms = get_terms('Custom Post Type Reg', $cat_args);
            $content = ' ';
            $content .= '<ul >';
                foreach($terms as $taxonomy){
                    $term_slug = $taxonomy->slug;
                    $cat_id = $taxonomy->term_id;
                    $tax_post_args = array(
                          'post_type' => 'Custom Post Type',
                          'posts_per_page' => 999,
                          'order' => 'ASC',
                          'numberposts' => -1,
                          'tax_query' => array(
                                array(
                                     'taxonomy' => 'Custom Post Type Reg',
                                     'field' => 'slug',
                                     'terms' => $term_slug,
                                     'id'    => $cat_id
                                ),
                           )
                    );    
                      $content .= '<li >'; 
                        $content .= '<div >';         
                            $content .= $taxonomy->name;
                                $the_query = null;
                                $the_query = new WP_Query( $tax_post_args );  
                                if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {                           
                                    $content .= '<ul >';
                                    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                                        $the_query->the_post();
                                        $content .= '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
                                    }                     
                                    $content .= '</ul>';
                                }             
                                wp_reset_postdata();       
                         $content .= '</div>';    
                      $content .= '</li>';           
                    } //end foreach loop
            $content .= '</ul>';
            return $content;

        }
        add_shortcode('shortcode', 'Custom_Post_Type_Grouped_By_Category');
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the it looks like you want to get all products grouped by category. Your query seems to be correct except `$term_slug` need not be in quotes.

```
$tax_post_args = array(
                  'post_type' => 'bpo_microsoftoffice',
                  'posts_per_page' => 999,
                  'order' => 'ASC',
                  'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                             'taxonomy' => 'bpo_microsoftoffice_reg',
                             'field' => 'slug',
                             'terms' => $term_slug
                        )
                   )
            );
```

Edit:

Method 1:

If you want just query you wrote, use `WP_Query($tax_post_args );`.

Method 2:

If you want both `category` plus `custom_taxonomy`, add `'category' => $cat_id,` in `$tax_post_args`.

So,

```
$tax_post_args = array(
              'post_type' => 'bpo_microsoftoffice',
              'posts_per_page' => 999,
              'order' => 'ASC',
              'tax_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                         'taxonomy' => 'bpo_microsoftoffice_reg',
                         'field' => 'slug',
                         'terms' => $term_slug
                    ),
                    array(
                         'taxonomy' => 'category',
                         'field' => 'slug',
                         'terms' => $cat_id
                    ),
               )
        );
```

And the use WP_Query($tax_post_args);

This is assuming your `post_type` is having `category` as well as `bpo_microsoftoffice_reg` as taxonomies. If only `bpo_microsoftoffice_reg` is assigned, use first method.

Comment: I did this 'terms' => '$term_slug' but its still printing all posts on all categories :-(

Comment: Try it without ' ' around `$term_slug`

Comment: If it doesn't work, `print_r($the_query)` and check if query is proper.

Comment: Seems to be correct. but its not grouping

Comment: Just noticed `$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'category' => $cat_id, 'post_type' => 'bpo_microsoftoffice' ) ); `. You're supposed to pass `$tax_post_args` to WP_Query()

Comment: I understand but I dont know how to pass it through WP_Query() cause its already using the id of the category

Comment: Check the edit if that's what you want.

Comment: No it didnt work :-(

Comment: Check for Typos and spellings, doesn't seem anything wrong with query

Comment: Got it! Thanks for Pointing out in the right direction :-)

Comment: Original code is updated in case someone needs it